# Sorting 10 words alphabetical order

Tags: java

I am grade 10 and struggling with a program.I need a program sorting 10 word alphabeticaly. My program is not working, it throws out the last word and if word1 stars with a, word2 starts with d and word3 with b and word4 with c it thows out word2 and print word3 2 times.

```
String word1, word2, word3, word4, word5, word6, word7, word8, word9, word10;
  word1 = "apple";
  word2 = "banana";
  word3 = "jelly";
  word4 = "jam";
  word5 = "Thandi";
  word6 = "Thomas";
  word7 = "hi";
  word8 = "Hi";
  word9 = "someone";
  word10 = "some-one";

   if (word1.compareTo(word2) <0)
  {
     System.out.print(word1);
  }
   else 
  {
     System.out.print(word2);
  }
```

Comment: `... without arrays` - where does that constraint come from? Are lists allowed?

Comment: Could you explain why you can't use an array? Also, the reason `word2` is omitted when `word1` comes before it alphabetically is because you only print `word2` in an `else` block. If `word1` comes first it won't run.

Comment: I am grade 10 and we only have learded JOptions, loops and if statments.

Comment: Tree structures can be used to sort too. But I don't believe you're discouraged from learning about arrays on your own, especially since it's a very basic topic and most likely you already use an array as parameter of the `main` method.

Comment: If you use arrays can you please explain how it works too me.

Comment: If you use a naive bubble or insertion sort method, for example, you are going to have to write 100 comparisons, or probably 300 lines of code. Unless you use a data structure (such as an array)... Solving your problem with 10 variables is just an unreasonable requirement so I suggest you asked your teacher if you can use arrays (and the answer will probably be yes)...

Comment: Oky thanks can you please show me how you would use arrays to solve the problem

Comment: By without `Arrays` do you mean to say without `Arrays.sort()` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[ ] args)
 {
         String[ ] names = {"apple","banana","jelly","jam","Thandi","Thomas","hi","Hi","someone","some-one"}; //This line creates an array and adds your values in to the created array
         sortStringExchange (names); //the method below is called
         for ( int k = 0;  k < names.length;  k++ )
            System.out.println( names [ k ] );      // prints all the values in the array in ascending order
  }

  public static void sortStringExchange( String  x [ ] )
  {
        int i, j;
        String temp;

        for ( i = 0;  i < x.length - 1;  i++ )
        {
            for ( j = i + 1;  j < x.length;  j++ )
            { 
                     if ( x [ i ].compareToIgnoreCase( x [ j ] ) > 0 )
                      {                                             // ascending sort
                                  temp = x [ i ];
                                  x [ i ] = x [ j ];    // swapping
                                  x [ j ] = temp;

                       }
               }
         }
  }
```

This is the simpler way

```
String[] strings = { "apple","banana","jelly","jam","Thandi","Thomas","hi","Hi","someone","some-one" };
Arrays.sort(strings);
```

Please read about array from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Comment: Thanks this will help me a lot.